# Issue with full outer join in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I use below 2 queries separately I get output successfully

Query #1

```
DECLARE @ID VARCHAR(1000) 
SET @ID = '' 

SELECT @ID = @ID + CAST(int_ID AS VARCHAR(1000)) 
FROM MATRIX_RELATIONSHIP 

SELECT COUNT(int_ID) [Count], YEAR(dt_5841_OF) [date] 
FROM TRANS_IDENTIFICATIONS 
WHERE smallint_209_ME = 4 
  AND CHARINDEX(CONVERT(VARCHAR, int_ID), ('''' + Replace((@ID),',',''',''') + '''')) > 0 
GROUP BY YEAR(dt_5841_OF);
```

Output:

```
        Count | year
          02    2016
```

Query #2

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) [Count1], YEAR(dt_modifiedOn) [date]
FROM 
    MATRIX_RELATIONSHIP 
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(dt_modifiedOn);
```

Output:

```
        Count | year
          02    2016
```

But when I use both queries to form a `full outer join` something like below:

```
SELECT 
    tab1.Count, tab2.Count1, tab1.date 
FROM
    (DECLARE @ID VARCHAR(1000) 
     SET @ID = '' 

     SELECT @ID = @ID+CAST(int_ID AS VARCHAR(1000)) 
     FROM MATRIX_RELATIONSHIP 

     SELECT COUNT(int_ID) [Count], YEAR(dt_5841_OF) [date] 
     FROM TRANS_IDENTIFICATIONS 
     WHERE smallint_209_ME = 4 
       AND CHARINDEX(convert(varchar,int_ID),  ('''' + Replace((@ID),',',''',''') + '''')) > 0 
     GROUP BY YEAR(dt_5841_OF)) tab1
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) [Count1], YEAR(dt_modifiedOn) [date]
     FROM MATRIX_RELATIONSHIP 
     GROUP BY YEAR(dt_modifiedOn)) tab2 ON tab1.date = tab2.date;
```

I get these errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near 'tab2'.

Expected result

```
Count | Count1 | year 
  02      02     2016
```

**EDIT**

I have tried placing declare and set outside the query too but still there the issue persists

```
DECLARE  @ID VARCHAR(1000) SET @ID=''
 SELECT tab1.Count,tab2.Count1,tab1.date from
( SELECT @ID= @ID+CAST(int_ID AS VARCHAR(1000)) 
from MATRIX_RELATIONSHIP SELECT COUNT(int_ID)[Count],YEAR(dt_5841_OF)[date] FROM TRANS_IDENTIFICATIONS WHERE smallint_209_ME=4 and CHARINDEX(convert(varchar,int_ID),  ('''' + Replace((@ID),',',''',''') + '''')) > 
0 GROUP BY YEAR(dt_5841_OF)) tab1
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT COUNT(*)[Count1],YEAR(dt_modifiedOn)[date]
 FROM MATRIX_RELATIONSHIP GROUP BY YEAR(dt_modifiedOn)) tab2
 ON tab1.date=tab2.date;
```

Which leads to another set of errors:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near '='.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
>   Incorrect syntax near 'tab2'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    DECLARE  @ID VARCHAR(1000) 
    SET @ID='';

    SELECT @ID = @ID + CAST(int_ID AS VARCHAR(1000)) from MATRIX_RELATIONSHIP;

    SELECT MAX(Count) AS Count, MAX(Count1) AS Count1, date
    FROM
    (

        SELECT COUNT(int_ID)[Count], null AS [Count1], YEAR(dt_5841_OF)[date] 
        FROM TRANS_IDENTIFICATIONS 
        WHERE smallint_209_ME = 4 
        and CHARINDEX(convert(varchar,int_ID),  ('''' + Replace((@ID),',',''',''') + '''')) > 
        0 GROUP BY YEAR(dt_5841_OF)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT NULL AS [Count],  COUNT(*)[Count1],YEAR(dt_modifiedOn)[date]
        FROM MATRIX_RELATIONSHIP 
        GROUP BY YEAR(dt_modifiedOn)
    )AS temp 
    GROUP BY [date]
```

Answer (score 1):

this is not a valid from
it is two select statements

```
from
( DECLARE  @ID VARCHAR(1000) 
  SET @ID='' SELECT @ID= @ID+CAST(int_ID AS VARCHAR(1000)) 
             from MATRIX_RELATIONSHIP 

  SELECT COUNT(int_ID)[Count],YEAR(dt_5841_OF)[date] 
  FROM TRANS_IDENTIFICATIONS 
  WHERE smallint_209_ME=4 
  and CHARINDEX(convert(varchar,int_ID), ('''' + Replace((@ID),',',''',''') + '''')) > 0 
  GROUP BY YEAR(dt_5841_OF)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your DECLARE and SET has to be outside of the SELECT. But what is its purpose?

Comment: @SiddP same to `SELECT @ID=` - it does not belong to full join.

Answer (score 0):

remove the  `DECLARE  @ID VARCHAR(1000);`
 `SET @ID=''`  from the select statement.
Also declare the variable at the top of your statement
and rather writing two separate select statement use inner join on int_id and then do the outer join it will work

Comment: I have already tried that you can see in question. it is leading to error

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @ID VARCHAR(1000) 
     SET @ID = '' 
     select * from
     (
SELECT    @ID+ CAST(MATRIX_RELATIONSHIP.int_ID AS varchar(1000)) AS count1, COUNT(TRANS_IDENTIFICATIONS.int_ID) AS count2, YEAR(TRANS_IDENTIFICATIONS.dt_5841_OF) AS date1
FROM         MATRIX_RELATIONSHIP INNER JOIN
                      TRANS_IDENTIFICATIONS ON MATRIX_RELATIONSHIP.int_ID = TRANS_IDENTIFICATIONS.int_ID
WHERE     (TRANS_IDENTIFICATIONS.smallint_209_ME = 4) AND (CHARINDEX(CONVERT(varchar, TRANS_IDENTIFICATIONS.int_ID), '''' + REPLACE(@ID, ',', ''',''') + '''') > 0)
GROUP BY YEAR(TRANS_IDENTIFICATIONS.dt_5841_OF),MATRIX_RELATIONSHIP.int_ID
union 
(
SELECT '' as count1, COUNT(*) [Count2], YEAR(dt_modifiedOn) [date1]
     FROM MATRIX_RELATIONSHIP 
     GROUP BY YEAR(dt_modifiedOn)
 )
 ) as tbl

I hope this works for you... Do let me know